# Turned off wifi in Windows, formated drive, can't turn on in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking

So...I may have made a huge mistake.  I can't get my wifi working on my work Lonovo T410 after formatting the drive with windows 7 on it.  I think the wifi may have been shut off when I obliterated the old install...

Here's what I know, when I run `lshw -C network`, I get this output:

```
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 35
   serial: 00:27:10:d7:b1:a0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:43 memory:f2400000-f2401fff
```

So it looks like there is a driver there, and it is installed correctly.  Though if anyone has guidance beyond Ubuntus own [troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers), I'd love to hear it.

I got this laptop to take to a programming conference this weekend, and wanted to quickly get Ubuntu up and running so that I could be productive when I got there.  In my rush I formatted the drive and threw Ubuntu 12.04 onto the laptop.

Small problem, the Windows 7 install was a fully configured install (they're just going to flash the laptop when I give it back, so no worries there.)  I think they had the wifi turned off for security purposes...  So now I can't turn the wifi on, no matter what I do.

The end of Ubuntu's official documentation says to just go to the old OS and turn the wifi on, but I don't have that option anymore (out of time...).  Does anyone know how to just force the wifi back on?

Comment: 'Disabled' usually refers to the wireless switch. What does this tell us? rfkill list all  What is the position of the wireless switch on the right hand side?